# Use of identical operator(===) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am very new to swift programming. I got stuck by the === operator in Swift. What is the basic use of identical operator (===) in Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`===` is the [identity operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID90), which tests if two variables refer to the same instance.
The equality operator `==` only tests if two objects are equal.

You can test the following code in a Playground:

```
let str1 = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
let str2 = str1
let str3 = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")

str1 == str2  // true
str1 == str3  // true
str1 === str2 // true
str1 === str3 // false
```